# Style A Tag Within A Tag Using Inline CSS

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to style a tag within a tag using inline css?

For example, is there a way to turn text red using something such as:

```
<div style="p {color:red;}">
<p>Some Red Text</p>
</div>
```

The editor for the application I'm using strips style tags and is generating p tags automatically so I can't use the normal methods. (External CSS sheets, also aren't an option).

I've looked around and can't see a way to do this, any help is appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: this isn't pure css? what language are you using, should just be: `<div style="color: red">`?

Comment: I'm trying to style the p tag within it using pure css, sorry I missed the semi-colon. I can't put the styling within the p tag as it's generated automatically.

Comment: "pure css" cant be used inline. Should try to use css like @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs suggested or try and make a `<style>` tag.

Comment: you can't style the `<p>` tag by adding style to the parent tag which is the `<div>`

Comment: @Adam you mean can*?

Comment: <div style="color:red;">
<p>Some Red Text</p></div>??????

Comment: I think the issue is that the p tag has styling from a master css sheet that is overriding any styling I put into the div tag.

Comment: can you edit your question so that information you gave in comments is easily accessible for everyone? (that's why you have repeated wrong answers). eg: "normal methods" is vague. please be clear

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline CSS in this way.

```
<p style="color:green">Some Red Text</p>
```

I create a [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dr0ngLv9/3/), you can have a look. Plus here a [good article](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) about stylesheets.

Comment: The p tag is generated automatically, I can't edit it inline like you have here.

Answer (score -4):

This is the answer:

just use - style="color:red" for the div styling

no need for the p{}

Comment: The p tag is being overridden by styling from a stylesheet, that won't work here. Thanks for your help.